# Sending Message using TCP Socket not returning any data

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, tcp

I am using following code

```
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();                           
                        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                        byte[] b = message.getBytes("US-ASCII");
                        String convertedString =   Normalizer.normalize(message, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
                        Log.d("ASCII", convertedString);
                        output.println(convertedString);
                        Log.e("TCP Message sent", convertedString);
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                            //read line(s)
                        String st = input.readLine();
                        Log.e("TCP Message received", st);
```

But I am stuck at String st = input.readLine(); It just hangs there and never proceed to next line. Is this correct way of sending message using TCLP And then get response?

Comment: Are you using println() at the other end too?

Comment: @user3001439 I have no idea what kind of code is being used on server side but it is working with my iPhone and windows code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting stuck at `readLine()` because the connection is still open - android is still waiting for more data to come in, and so can't move on.

This is what I did, but whether this is viable may depend on the protocol you are adhering to.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != ""){
    builder.append(line);
}
Log.i("data", builder.toString());
```

Comment: @Muhammad try using a DataInputStream instead of a BufferedReader

Comment: I have tried but i always get timeOutexception. It seems that out is not sending message to server somehow, tho the port and address is correct

Comment: @Muhammad - can you see on the server whether the data is received?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `flushing your output stream` after sending message by:

```
output.flush();
```

or use auto flush by passing true while creating Output Stream like this:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: did this but still stuck

Comment: Same thing needs to be applied at other end i mean your socket server

Comment: The server is fine have tested on other end devices too. It should send me "ACK" but is not sending, message is ok, If i use the same message it works on SocketController software for mac

Comment: I have no idea what kind of code is being used on server side but it is working with my iPhone and windows code and also with Sockettest tool for mac